# Select Dropdown Appears Underneath Page

Tags: html, css

I've got a select dropdown I was hoping to have at the bottom of the page.  Unfortunately when you click on the select, it appears underneath the page, not allowing me to select a different value.

It is on the very bottom of a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page.  I'm not sure how I would go around to fixing this, I have a feeling that it's the footer's CSS.

## HTML

```
footer#footer.stats-bar.row.content
  .well
    .footer-row
      select.that-wont-dropdown
```

## CSS

```
// Footer: Fixed bottom
#footer
  position fixed
  border 0
  padding-top 0
  bottom 0
  margin-left 0
  left 0
  right 0

  .footer-row
    clear both
    overflow hidden

  .left
    margin-right 0
    width 33%
    float: left

  .well
    width 100%
    height auto
    margin 0
    padding 10px 0 0 0
```

In the short term I'm just going to move it to the top of the footer, but I'm interested to know why Chrome doesn't display the select correctly.

Comment: Remove the overflow:hidden and see what happens?

Comment: Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191962/prevent-select-from-running-off-bottom-of-css-dropdown-menu) about forcing a "drop up" using JavaScript

Comment: I'm not going to include a 3rd party's JS and CSS just to have a select display correctly.  I'll take a look and see if `overflow: hidden;` fixes the issue, though I don't think it will. EDIT: Actually, when I put padding on the `.well`, it somehow fixes the select.  I did move the HTML around so the select is outside the `.well` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the reason why this was happening was due to the funky way of doing the footer.  After playing with padding and margins, it mysteriously started appearing where you'd expect it. I'm chalking this up to a Chrome bug.